# Export Library.scpt: execution error: Can’t set «class valL» of «class txtf» 1 of window 1 to "testing". (-10006)

Tags: applescript

The script is invoked with "osascript Export\ Library.scpt /Users/bryandunphy/Development/iTunesLibraryConsolidator testing".

The error occurs on the last line.

Here is the relevant code:

```
on run (clp)
    if clp's length is not 2 then error "Incorrect Parameters"
    local destination, libraryName
    set destination to clp's item 1
    set libraryName to clp's item 2
    menuClick({"iTunes", "File", "Library", "Export Library…"})
    set the value of the front window's text field 1 to libraryName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script works with iTunes 12.5.5.5 using macOS Sierra:

```
tell application "System Events" to set value of text field "Save As:" of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes" to "yourNewLibraryName"
```

Or, to adjust it to your variable:

```
tell application "System Events" to set value of text field "Save As:" of window "iTunes" of application process "iTunes" to libraryName
```

By the way, you can use `text field 1` as well.

Does this work for you?

Comment: Yes, perfectly and I'm stall running EL Capitan with iTunes 12.5.5 as well